# Error with positive stateDuration parameter

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using datatables 1.10.0 with the following option:

```
"bStateSave": true,
"stateDuration": 0,
```

After playing around with a new version of datatables and rolling back, I got a `TypeError` in the datatables javascript, only for a few tables. After investigation, it appears that the `stateDuration` parameter is guilty. When set to `-1` (which means session storage), there is no error, when set to anything else (which means local storage duration in seconds), the error occurs.
I tried to remove firefox cache, related cookies, the error persists.
Any idea ?

Comment: There is no differences in internal `fnStateLoadCallback` / `fnStateSaveCallback` from 1.10.0 to 1.10.9 ...

Comment: In FF : 1) Open devtools / firebug with F12... 2) Goto the console tab 3) In the bottom there is a box where you can type text. type `allow paste` and then paste `;localStorage.clear();`